# mouse crashes after sleeping mode

Tags: mouse, asus, crash

I've installed Ubunutu 14.04 on my laptop, but I have a little problem. If I use sleep mode on my PC (closing it), after opening it, my mouse stops using. I can't click and can't move it neither. I tried to push "fn+f9", because it is the shortcut on my computer (asus) to turn off the mouse. It works normally, but after sleeping mode it shows only off mode...
Have you got any answers or I have to reinstall it?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Same problem bro, upgrade to 15.10. Use the "Software Update" tool. It'll update just about everything thats in the repositories you've got setup.

Edit: you need to update all your software before you can upgrade the install. the same tool does it.

Comment: It could not work. Let's just see the results.